# NSPredicate against NSArray in iphone

Tags: iphone, search, nsarray, filtering, nspredicate

How can I use `NSPredicate` to filter the values from array ivar against search query ? I manage to use `NSPredicate` against string ivar. I have one user defined class named as "User" which is used to create User from AddressBook. Here is my code

```
  // User Defined Class named as "User"

// In User.h

@interface User : NSObject {

    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *lastName;
    NSString *company;
    UIImage *userImage;

    NSArray *phoneNumberArray;
    NSArray *emailArray;
    NSArray *urlArray;
    NSArray *addressArray;

    NSString *notes;
    NSString *dateOfBirth;
}

// In SearchViewController.m

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

    //  contactsArray is NSMutableArray   
    contactsArray = [Search searchContactsWithQuery:searchText];
    NSLog(@"contactsArray count => %d",[contactsArray count]);
    [contactsTableView reloadData];
}

// In Search.m

+(NSMutableArray*)searchContactsWithQuery:(NSString*)query {

    NSLog(@"Query => %@",query);

    NSMutableArray*  predicates=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Create all predicates
    NSPredicate * firstNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName contains %@",query];
    [predicates addObject:firstNamePredicate];
    NSPredicate * lastNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastName contains %@",query];
    [predicates addObject:lastNamePredicate];
    NSPredicate * companyPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"company contains %@",query];
    [predicates addObject:companyPredicate];

    // Don't know how to use on array
    // === START of ARRAY Predicate ====

NSPredicate *phoneNoPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phoneNumberArray IN %@",query];
    [predicates addObject:phoneNoPredicate];

    NSPredicate *emailPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"emailArray contains %@",query];
    [predicates addObject:emailPredicate];
    NSPredicate *urlPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"urlArray contains %@",query];
    [predicates addObject:urlPredicate];

    NSPredicate *addressPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"addressArray contains %@",query];

    // === END of ARRAY Predicate ====

    NSPredicate *notesPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"notes contains %@",query];
    [predicates addObject:notesPredicate];
    NSPredicate *dobPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dateOfBirth contains %@",query];
    [predicates addObject:dobPredicate]; 

    // Add predicates to array
    NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];

    NSArray * filteredArray = [APP_DELEGATE.allUsersArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundPredicate];

    return [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:filteredArray];

}
```

phoneNumberArray,emailArray,urlArray & addressArray are used because user may have multiple entries for phone no , email, address , url like HOME , WORK, iPhone, Other etc.

How can I use predicates on array? Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` is the right way to go. Is the code above not working? Are you sure that there's a value in the array that matches the predicate?

Comment: There are values in array that matches predicate

Comment: Try simplifying your predicate. Instead of using the compound predicate, try filtering the array with one of your simple predicates. Indeed, you could try applying them each to get 9 separate arrays -- that may give you a clue as to where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the correct way, but you need to create your Predicates with String values instead of passing the Objects directly.

You need to use %k instead of %@ like

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName contains %k",query];`

Please let me know if this helps.